# JavaScript Echo Var Within Double Quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay,

Another novice type question.

I have this array within the `head` section on my website and want to use it inline JavaScript:

```
var MyVariable = {"chkboxid":"chkbox"}
```

**chkboxid** is a id of a checkbox input.

Now, while validating the checkbox input on form submit, neither this works

```
$("form#myform").submit(function () {
        if ($(MyVariable.chkboxid).is(":checked")) {
        } else {
            alert(CommentsPlus.nochkboxmsg);
            return false;
        }
```

Nor This (check the double quote at the variable)

```
$("form#myform").submit(function () {
        if ($("MyVariable.chkboxid").is(":checked")) {
        } else {
            alert(CommentsPlus.nochkboxmsg);
            return false;
        }
```

However, if I hardcode the checkbox input id, it works. I mean `"input#chkbox"` in place of `MyVariable.chkboxid`.

```
$("form#myform").submit(function () {
        if ($("input#chkbox").is(":checked")) {
        } else {
            alert(CommentsPlus.nochkboxmsg);
            return false;
        }
```

How can I use that variable instead of hard coding the input id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the "#" before the ID:

```
$("form#myform").submit(function () {
    var element = $("#" + MyVariable.chkboxid)
    if (element.is(":checked")) {
    } else {
        alert(CommentsPlus.nochkboxmsg);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note however that *chkboxid* is the **key**, the actual ID of the checkbox should be the value:

```
var MyVariable = {"chkboxid": "real_id_here"}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check below code.hope it will work
`$("form#myform").submit(function () {
        if ($("#chkboxid").is("checked")) {alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("not checked");
        }
});`

thanks,Ripa Saha